# Problem With LINQ Model - Can't Assign NULL To Nullable Boolean!

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2005, serialization, linq-to-sql

I have a LINQ model containing an entity which is populated by a stored procedure.  A couple of the fields returned by the procedure are nullable bit fields, so I've created these as nullable booleans on the model.  I'd expect this to work fine, but when I run my application I get the following exception from `System.Runtime.Serialization`...

> The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the
>   message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter
>   urn:Nbs.PrePaidCards.ChargebackService:GetUnlinkedChargebacksAndRepresentmentsResult.
>   The InnerException message was 'ValueType 'System.Boolean' cannot be
>   null.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.

Now I'd understand this if I was trying to populate a regular `bool` field with a `null`, but since the property is `Nullable`, this has me a bit stumped!

Had anyone else had this problem and know how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your DBML is up-to-date with the database? Also, could you show the code that triggers the error?

Comment: It seems assigning a null to a non nullable bool, You will have to post the code else no way we would know it here

Comment: The strange thing is, I have another class on the same model with nullable bools and that's working fine.  I'm using a SQL Server 2005 database.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was caused by an out of date service reference on my client, so whilst the service had a nullable bool field, the proxy on the client was still expecting a regular bool field, hence the serialization exception.

Comment: Make sure your service references in your client projects are up to date, my problem was caused by a conflict between the data contracts exposed by my service being different to those expected by the client.